# Custom QGridLayout items selection behaviour

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, grid-layout

How can I change behavior of how items are selected in QGridLayout by cursor keys? I want to move selection horizontally by left/right cursor keys and vertically by up/down keys.
Who is responsible for it? Layout, items container or tab order?

Comment: Lyout is not responsible for anything that relates to focus AFAIK. Widgets are responsible themselves for handling focus and tab order. As hank has said, you'll need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reimplement `keyPressEvent()` method for the main widget to catch the pressed keys. Then you can access the desired widget in your layout by calling `QGridLayout::itemAtPosition (int row, int column)` and then set focus to it.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do this way but keyPressEvent was not called in my widget (just keyReleasedEvent) or even main event handler (def event(self, target, event)) was not receiving QEvent.KeyPress. I ended up installing eventFilter for every widget in the QGridLayout which handles key events and sets focus to the calculated widget.